# probablity that needle is $i-th$ haystack

Tags: probability

needle is in one among $1,...,n$ haystacks. We know that in $i-th$ haystack is with probablity $p_i$. If needle is in $i-th$ haystack then when we search this haystack we found it with probablity $a_i$.

What is probablity that needle is in $j−th$ stack - we assume that BEFORE we tried find in $i−th$ stack, but we hadn't found ($i,j=1...n$).

So I try:
$S_i$- probablity that neddle is in $ith$ haystack
$Z_i$ - probablity that we found needle in $i-th$ haystack
$N_i$ probablity that we didn;t find needle in $i-th$ haystack

We must find: $Pr(S_j|N_i)$
$$Pr(S_j|N_i) = \frac{P(N_i|S_j)\cdot P(S_j)}{P(N_i)} $$
$$i \neq k  \rightarrow P(N_i|S_k)P(S_k) = 1\cdot p_k$$
$$i = k  \rightarrow P(N_i|S_i)P(S_i) = (1-a_i)p_i$$
$$P(N_i) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}p_k - p_i + (1-a_i)p_i $$
So the answer is:
$$Pr(S_j|N_i) = \frac{p_j}{= \sum_{k=1}^{n}p_k - p_i + (1-a_i)p_i } $$

What about this solution ?

Comment: Don't you need to find $P(Z_j\mid N_i)$, not $P(S_j\mid N_i)$?

Comment: Ok, I wrongly ask question: What is probablity that needle is in $j-th$ stack - we assume that BEFORE we tried find in $i-th$ stack, but we hadn't found. So we must compute $P(S_j|N_i)$. Ok ?

Comment: Ok, thanks. You might like to edit your question to change this part "What is probablity that we find needle in j−th  haystack".

Comment: Ok, I edited. Could you look at my solution, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks correct to me. Two notes:

1. $\sum_{k=1}^n{p_k} = 1$ and also we have $p_i$ and $-p_i$ cancelling each other, so we can simplify the solution to:
   $$Pr(S_j\mid N_i) = \frac{p_j}{1 - a_ip_i}.$$
2. A slightly simpler way to calculate $P(N_i)$:

$$P(N_i) = 1-P(N_i^c) = 1 - P(N_i^c\cap S_i) = 1-P(N_i^c\mid S_i)P(S_i) = 1-a_ip_1.$$

Comment: Thanks you again! ;) Tell me if I properly understand: $P(N_i^c)$ means that we FIND neadly

Comment: Yes, that's right.